# What are wish and if-clause called as a group?

Tags: syntax, subjunctive, conditionals, grammatical-category

I'm not sure about the grammatical category of wish and if-clause. I have found some names like hypothetical sentences, conditional, subjunctive mood. But I don't think they are the academic name for this type of grammatical structure. Does anyone know the name for it?

Comment: Conditional _if_ expressions are not clauses. They are PPs with "if" as head and a content clause as complement.

Comment: Well, yes, but the clause is the important constituent; the P may be disregarded once its introductory duty is done, like a complementizer. As for the question, the distinction between possibility and impossibility is crucial. For the complement of _wish_, the term is "counterfactual", meaning 'it's not fact; it's imagination'. For _if_-clauses, they can be counterfactual, and then they get marked with past forms: _If wishes were horses, then beggars would ride_; but they can also be simply hypothesis: _If this place serves coffee, I'm having breakfast here._

Comment: Oh, and "counterfactual" is not a name for "_wish_ and _if_-clauses". It's a name for the meaning, not the construction. For instance, there are other verbs that govern counterfactual complements besides _wish_, and there are some _if_-clauses that don't.